# How to initialize CameraController with SharedPreferences?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sharedpreference

First I have initialized my camera controller ([camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera): ^0.9.4+11) like this and it works:

```
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final CameraDescription camera;

  const TakePictureScreen({required Key key, required this.camera}) 
    : super(key: key);

  @override
  TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  late CameraController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = CameraController(
      widget.camera,
      ResolutionPreset.max, // TODO: this should come from SharedPreferences
    );
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
            ? CameraPreview(_controller)
            : Text("");
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But now I want to load the `ResolutionPreset` dynamically from SharedPreferences ([shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences): ^2.0.13).
What's a good way to do this?

I failed when trying it like this (adding some variables and changing `initState` method):

```
final Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
late Future<int> _resolutionIndex;
List<ResolutionPreset> resolutions = ResolutionPreset.values.toList(growable: false);
static const String sharedPrefResolution = "resolution";

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _resolutionIndex = _prefs.then((SharedPreferences prefs) {
    int resolutionIndex = prefs.getInt(sharedPrefResolution) ?? (resolutions.length - 1);
    _controller = CameraController(
      widget.camera,
      resolutions[resolutionIndex],
    );
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
    return resolutionIndex;
  });
}
```

Getting the error: `LateInitializationError: Field '_initializeControllerFuture@19039262' has not been initialized.`

Comment: Have you tried debugging this section of code and seeing what happens (perhaps use logs)? Also, have you considered changing this variable to be nullable instead of late?

Comment: @tomerpacific thanks for the suggestion, making it nullable got rid of the error - but the image never showed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initState` can't be an `async` method, and getting a value from `SharedPreferences` is an `async` function. You can't use `await` (or `then`) in `initState`, I mean you can use but the code execution will not wait for this to complete. So what happens here is that your `build` method will run earlier than the future getting the value from `SharedPreferences` completes. And as I presume your `_initializeControllerFuture` is marked as `late`, so when your `build` tries to use it, it is still `null`, and that will get you this error.

The common way to solve this issue is to use a `FutureBuilder`. Get the values from `SharedPreferences` with [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), display a progress indicator while it is being loaded (it will be quick so if you think you can skip this part), and then when you get the value from it, build your widget using the value coming from `SharedPreferences`, and initialize `CameraController` only after this.

Comment: Thanks, after putting another `FutureBuilder` around my FutureBuilder it seemed to work :)

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome!